# Return elements of a column based on a different column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to write a program to return names in a list based on the number of reports in descending order.
like ['Jack', 'Joe', 'Rick'....]

```
df=
Number_of_reports  Name
5                   Rick
4                   Amanda
7                   Joe
8                   Jack
2                   Ryan
```

```
mylist=[]
greater_value=0
for i in df['Number_of_Reports']:
    if greater_value > i:
        mylist.append(df['Name'])
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

`names = df.sort_values(by='Number_of_reports', ascending=False)['Name'].tolist()`

Which gives:

`['Jack', 'Joe', 'Rick', 'Amanda', 'Ryan']`